# Hartshorne problem III.4.10

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I am stuck on this problem from Hartshorne and to be honest I don't really know where to start. The problem is the following: $X$ is a non-singular variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$. Then we have to show that there is a one to one correspondence
$$\{\text{Infinitesimal extensions of $X$ by $\mathcal{F}$}\}/\text{iso}\leftrightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{T})$$
where $\mathcal{T}=\mathscr{H}om(\Omega_{X/k},\mathcal{O}_X)$ is the tangent sheaf. I had the following idea: Let $(X',\mathcal{J})$ be an infinitesimal extension (we may assume $X'=X$ as topological spaces). Cover $X$ by a finite number of open affine $U_i$. Then $(U_i',\mathcal{J}|_{U_i'})$ is an extension of $U_i$ by $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}$. By problem $II.8.7$ in Hartshorne we know these extensions are trivial. So we get isomorphisms
$$\varphi_i:\mathcal{O}_{U_i'}\cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i}\oplus \mathcal{F}|_{U_i}.$$
Somehow I wanted to use these isomorphisms to construct a cycle in $\breve{C}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{T})$ but I don't know how. As I said I don't know if this is the way to start, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're doing fine so far. Here's a hint for where to go next: consider two trivializations $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_j$ on their overlap $U_i\cap U_j$. These might not be the same, but you should be able to view their difference in terms of something you've already seen hanging around the infinitesimal lifting problems. Let me know how helpful this is, and if necessary I can give you more (up to an answer, if you'd like).

Comment: I think we can choose the isomorphisms $\varphi_i$ so that $(\varphi_i-\varphi_j)$ land in $\mathcal{F}$ on $U_i\cap U_j$. Then, if I set $\sigma_{ij}=\varphi_i(1)-\varphi_j(1)$ i get a cech cocycle $\sigma\in \breve{C}^2(X,\mathcal{F})$. Im not sure how to get $\mathcal{T}$ involved though.

Comment: No, that's not quite right - you want a 1-cocycle. Look at exercise II.8.6 again and the map from $\Omega_{X/k}$ mentioned there. (This is also a hint about how the tangent sheaf shows up.)

Comment: My bad, I confused myself. Thanks! Im gonna think more about it.

Comment: Thanks Kreiser I think I get the idea now : Given isomorphisms $\varphi_i$ as above we get derivations over $U_{ij}$ $(\varphi_i-\varphi_j):\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{F}$. The collection of these derivations we can think of as a cocycle in $\breve{C}^1(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{T})$. Conversely if we are given a collection of derivations $\alpha_{ij}:\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{F}$ we can construct a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_{X'}$ by setting $\mathcal{O}_{X'}=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{F}$ on each $U_i$ and glue them together with isomorphisms

Comment: over $U_{ij}$ $\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{F}$ which are given by matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}Id_{\mathcal{O}_X}&0\\ \alpha_{ij}&Id_\mathcal{F}\end{pmatrix}.$$
$\alpha_{ij}$ being a derivation makes this an isomorphism of sheaves of rings and the cocycle condition for $\alpha=(\alpha_{ij})$ tells us that these isomorphisms are compatible on triple intersections so we can glue together the sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_{X'}$!

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it. Would you like to write up your work as an answer and post it below to help others with this problem in the future? Alternatively, I could post a solution.

Comment: I don't think I want to write it out to be honest. If you have time, feel free to post a solution. Thanks again for your help!